# ¿Como escribir un condicional IF para una consulta SQL where con OR en PHP?

Tags: php, android, android-studio, webservice

**INTRODUCCION:**

Estoy programando un web service (servicio web) en PHP para conectar con mi aplicación en Android Studio. Dicho WS realiza una consulta a mi base de datos con el condicional OR

```
$consulta="select email, telefono from datos_registro where email = '{$email}' or telefono = '{$telefono}'";
```

**ADJUNTO EL CÓDIGO DE MI WEB SERVICE:**

```
<?PHP
$hostname_localhost="localhost";
$database_localhost="censored"; //CENSURADO POR SEGURIDAD
$username_localhost="censored";
$password_localhost="censored";

$json=array();

    $email=$_GET["email"];
    $telefono=$_GET["telefono"];
            
    $conexion = 
mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);

    $consulta="select email, telefono from datos_registro where email = '{$email}' or telefono = 
'{$telefono}'";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
        
    if($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $result["email"]=1;
        $result["telefono"]=1;
        $json['datos'][]=$result;
    }else{
        $resultar["email"]=0;
        $resultar["telefono"]=0;
        $json['datos'][]=$resultar;
    }
        
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

**DESCRIPCIÓN DEL PROBLEMA:**

Lo que hago actualmente en este servicio web es consultar por email y telefono (que llegan desde la app android). Si alguno de estos dos datos coincide con un mail o telefono dentro de la base de datos, entonces el servicio web retornará un número 0 (cero). De lo contrario (en caso de que estos dos datos no existan o no estén repetidos), retornará un 1 (uno).

**¿CUAL ES EL PROBLEMA?**

Si uno de los dos datos ya existe en la B.D., entonces, sin importar que dato exista, ambas variables se pondrán con un numero 0 (cero).

**ACLARACIÓN:**

Si el email ingresado en la app no existe en la base de datos, pero si existe el telefono ingresado, entonces (gracias al web service que programé) tanto el email como el telefono van a tener un numero 0 (cero) indicando que ambos valores ya existen en la B.D. cuando, en realidad, solamente existe el telefono y no el email.

**CONCLUSIÓN:**

Para sintetizar, quiero modificar el código de mi web service (más específicamente el condicional if) para que sea exacto: es decir que si el mail no existe en la B.D. pero si existe el telefono, el mail tenga un 1 (uno) y el telefono tenga un 0 (cero)

**Muchas gracias por leer!**

**EDIT:**

Si no es posible resolver mi problema, me gustaría al menos que me ayuden adjuntando información para poder resolverlo.

Comment: Ya pero... aquí podemos echarte una mano con un error concreto... no vamos a hacer una modificación a tu código gratis para ti. Lo que yo veo en esta "pregunta" es un documento de requerimientos, y esos me gusta recibirlos con un adjunto en el que se aclara el dinero a percibir por el trabajo! Ahora en serio, si no tienes un error concreto te invito a que intentes modificarlo tú mismo, o que vayas a algún sitio de programadores freelancer y hables con uno para que lo haga por ti, pues aquí no nos dedicamos a eso!

Comment: Hola @Benito-B y gracias por responder. Me hizo gracia el chiste, pero dejandolo de lado, no veo por que no podría la gente ayudarme a realizar esta pequeña modificación. Si leíste toda mi publicación (100% detallada (por lo que el error es bien concreto)) te darás cuenta que solamente estoy requiriendo a un programador, ni siquiera avanzado, de PHP para que modifique solamente la condición del if a punto tal que me permita lograr lo solicitado en la conclusión. Saludos!

Comment: Y que intentaste? porque lo que estas pidiendo esta en el codigo descripto.. solo hay que modificar algunos ordenes de cosas... que fallo cuando lo intentaste?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi y gracias por responder. Lo que intenté está adjuntado en la parte "ADJUNTO EL CODIGO DE MI WEB SERVICE". El fallo está explicado en la parte "¿CUAL ES EL PROBLEMA?". Podrías ayudarme a ordenar las cosas que mencionas? Saludos!

Comment: yo no se php.. pero es simplemente leer lo que trae la query, los registros, y fijarse que variable devolver segun lo que viene en el campo...

Comment: @gbianchi no te preocupes. Es exactamente eso que mencionas, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo. Si tenés algo de información la agradecería.

Comment: Lo siento @TomasM, pero esto que dices: "***solamente estoy requiriendo a un programador, ni siquiera avanzado, de PHP para que modifique***" es literalmente una oferta de trabajo, no una consulta de un error concreto... Por eso me refiero a que tu pregunta no es correcta para lo que se hace en SO. Aquí arreglamos errores, y aunque eso no hace lo que tu quieres, no es por un error, si no porque tú lo hiciste así en su momento, y ahora quieres que otro te lo modifique (que trabaje para ti), gratis. Nosotros no podemos saber si realmente intentaste modificarlo tú ya o no, solo vemos lo que hay.

Comment: @Benito-B acabo de hacer una segunda modificación en mi publicación mostrando la solucion y lo tan simple que era lo que estaba buscando. Dudo que alguien me haya querido cobrar por modificar menos de 40 caracteres :D. Saludos!

Comment: @TomasM si encontraste la solución, entonces la misma va en la zona de respuestas y no en la pregunta

Comment: @Tomas M eso que has dicho de los 40 caracteres quiero pensar que no lo has dicho con mala intención, pero estás faltando el respeto a todo el que se dedica profesionalmente a la programación. Para poner esos caracteres hay que haber estudiado, superado exámenes, pruebas de admisión etc. Te estás pasando por alto que para poner esos caracteres hay que hacer un proceso de análisis previo que suele llevar mucho tiempo para después cambiar solo unas pocas letras. Tú quieres ir por la vía rápida y que te lo resuelvan pero respeta a los que nos lo hemos currado para llegar donde estamos

Comment: @BetaM no tenía idea de eso beta, gracias por mencionarlo. Ya mismo lo corrijo para que más personas se puedan beneficiar :)

Comment: Hola @ordago . No me pasé por alto ningún detalle como mencionas, por eso me tomé un buen tiempo para redactar esta publicación y dejarla lo más clara, resumida y entendible posible para los lectores, justamente para evitar comentarios de personas que no demuestran ninguna intención de ayudar.  Claramente que para poner esos menos de 40 caracteres hay que haber estudiado y, de hecho, pude resolverlo por mi propia cuenta como habrás podido leer. Para finalizar, en todo momento respondí amablemente y demostré ganas de seguir aprendiendo. Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

A ver.. ¿para algo inventaron la documentación no?

Entonces.. según la documentación de [mysqli_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php), esta función devuelve un array asociativo con los datos de la fila...

Con lo cual, ya tenes los datos de la fila...

Y ahora, solo tenes que comparar cada resultado de la columna con lo que queres...

```
if($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
```

Según la documentación, en **`$registro`** hay un array con datos...

Entonces podemos hacer:

```
if($registro[email] == "") {
    //el email esta vacio
```

Y lo mismo para el teléfono.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Me sirve tu respuesta por lo que la voto positiva, aunque por suerte pude solucionarlo por mi propia cuenta. Hago un segundo edit en la publicación para mostrar mi resolución. Saludos!

Comment: @TomasM la respuesta a la pregunta, va en la seccion respuesta, explicada como corresponde...

Comment: No sabía. Gracias por avisar @gbianchi

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolver el problema haciendo una MUY leve modificación. Adjunto las únicas dos líneas que modifiqué:

```
$result["email"]=$registro['email'];
$result["telefono"]=$registro['telefono'];
```

Gracias a esto, ahora puedo recibir tanto el email como el telefono en mi aplicación android. Al obtener estos datos, simplemente los manipulo con un condicional if.

Answer (score 0):

tu problema es muy sencillo de resolver. Lo único que debes hacer es una consulta a la base de datos donde le digas cuantos registros tienen el teléfono solicitado o el correo solicitado, si el resultado es mayor a cero que devuelva 1 como respuesta.

Si después de eso quieres que se modifique la base de datos puedes hacer un

```
UPDATE datos_registro SET telefono = 1, correo = 1 WHERE telefono = "{$telefono}" OR correo = "{$correo}";
```

Saludos.